# Replace a string if it starts with a certain character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dictionary

I am trying to use Pandas `map` to assign values to keys, where the keys would be strings returned if an entry in the DataFrame starts with a certain character.

Using an example from the Pandas docs, with the following DataFrame and my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'rabbit'])

s.map({ lambda x: x if x.startswith('c') else None: 'kitten', 
        lambda x: x if x.startswith('d') else None: 'puppy',
        lambda x: x if x.startswith('r') else None: 'bunny',
    })
```

Expected result:

```
0    kitten
1     puppy
2       NaN
3     bunny
dtype: object
```

Currently, my code returns 4 `NaN` values. I am specifying `startswith` because I am not always able to know the last characters of the string in my DataFrame, but I know the first character/s. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry I just decided to go with the answer from Shinra. I could mark your answer as the correct one if you'd like.

Comment: @Suva23 you should choose as accepted the answer that solved your problem really. I personally think his answer shows a better understanding of pandas and it's the one I would have selected aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead function `lambda` is possible create dictionary and mapping first letter by indexing `str[0]`:

```
print (s.str[0].map({'c': 'kitten', 'd': 'puppy', 'r': 'bunny'}))
0    kitten
1     puppy
2       NaN
3     bunny
dtype: object
```

If lengths of strings for test subtrings are different, not always same length:

```
d = {'ca': 'kitten', 'd': 'puppy', 'rab': 'bunny'}

for k, v in d.items():
    s.loc[s.str.startswith(k, na=False)] = v
print (s)
0    kitten
1     puppy
2       NaN
3     bunny
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store in a dictionary the mapping of first letter -> value, then use only one lambda function to lookup the corresponding value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mapping = {'c': 'kitten', 'd': 'puppy', 'r': 'bunny'}

s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'rabbit'])

s.map(lambda x: mapping.get(x[0]) if x else None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and regex:

```
dct = {'^c.*': 'kitten', '^d.*': 'puppy', '^r.*': 'bunny'}
s.replace(dct, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    kitten
1     puppy
2       NaN
3     bunny
dtype: object
```